# Initialise Excel Color Picker with colour VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following to open the color picker:

`Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPatterns).Show`

I've tried using the following to initialise with a color:

`Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPatterns).Show(1, RGBRed, RGBGreen, RGBBlue)`

Where RGBRed, RGBGreen, RGBBlue are defined as Long of 255,0,0 for testing (I'll be grabbing this value from a textbox eventually) but it throws an error with the parameters, any ideas on how I set it to be a color?

Comment: Is that the whole line, or are you doing something with the return value such as printing it or assigning it to a variable? Because I get the error "Expected: =" if I try to run it by itself, but it displays a dialogue box if I print its value. Note also that Integer in VBA is a 16-bit type, and RGB values are Long.

Comment: You may also be interested in `xlDialogEditColor`, which opens the colour editor dialogue and populates it with the RGB values as specified in parameters 2 to 4.

Comment: Is your end-result to show that specific dialog with a specific color or are you actually trying to let the user pick a color (while setting the initial color in that dialog and, presumably, getting the selected color back)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion from jsheeran I went with the following :

```
If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(10, lRed, lGreen, lBlue) = True Then
        'user pressed OK
        lColor = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(10)
    Else
        'user pressed Cancel
    End If
```

Where lColor, lRed, lGreen, lBlue are all defined as Long